# passing data to another controller

Tags: model-view-controller, magento

I need to pass product Id from cart to custom controller, for example
http://****/catalogsearch/filter/results?product={ID}

I dont have a clue how to pass data like that using magento helpers etc
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming from your question that you are redirecting from one controller to another and would like to pass query parameters along?

The syntax would be:

```
$params = array('key' => 'value');
$this->_redirect('frontname/controlller/action', array('_query' => $params));
```

**EDIT**

To answer the question in the comment on how to get these parameters from a template:

First off, I would advise not to do this, you should be recieving parameters in the controller.  So, your custom controller should be responsible for receiving any parameters.

Regardless, the code in either situation is the same:

All parameters…

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams()
```

Single parameter…

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('parameter_name')
```

Comment: thanks, but not exactly what i want.
i meant that there is some method in controller that receives params, and i want to call it from the cart.phtml